# How to create an adjacency matrix based on a condition in R?

Tags: r, adjacency-matrix

I came across the Q&A: [Possible-clique-numbers-of-a-regular-graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347672/possible-clique-numbers-of-a-regular-graph).

I have a `vec` vector and I need to create a adjacency matrix `A` such that `A[i,j]=1` if `i−j mod n` is an element of `vec` and `A[i,j]=0` otherwise.

My attempt:

```
k   <- 4
n   <- 10
vec <- c(seq(-k+1, -1), seq(1, k+1))

A <- matrix(0, n, n)

for (i in 1:n)
for (j in 1:n)
A[i,j] <- if((i - j) %% n in vec) 1
```

I get this error:

> Error: unexpected 'in' in:
>   "for (j in 1:n)
>   A[i,j] <- if((i - j) %% n in"

Question: how to create an `(n x n)`-adjacency matrix based on the condition?

Expected result is:

[image]

Comment: Can you add your expected output `A` for the sample `vec` you give?

Comment: PS. There is no `in` function in R but there is `%in%` (hence your error).

Comment: I don't understand why your output matrix is symmetric (see my comment below).

Comment: Your described logic does not seem to give your expected result.

Comment: @bluk, I came across the Q&A: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3347672/possible-clique-numbers-of-a-regular-graph , maybe I should to change the ordering from 0 to 1 in the conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
k   <- 4
n   <- 10
vec <- c(seq(1, k-1), seq(n-k+1, n-1))  # changed

A <- matrix(0, n, n)
for (i in 1:n) for (j in 1:n)  A[i,j] <- (abs(i-j%%n)) %in% vec # changed
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your logic here. From what I understood OP needs to create an adjacency matrix (with some distance metric) based on `vec`. So the resulting matrix will have dimension `m x m` where `m` is the length of `vec`. In your case, you populate an `n x n` matrix where `n` is 10 and `length(vec)` is 6. There seems to be no connection between `n` and `length(vec)`. You could've equally populated a `10000 x 10000` matrix (just set `n <- 10000` and re-run your `for` loop).

Comment: @MauritsEvers Guess the way this question is stated has led to some different interpretations. My understanding is that OP is trying to get an adjacency matrix which replicates the graph in the accepted answer of his quoted question, so when `n=10`, it will give a matrix corresponding to how the vertexes of a 10-side regular polygon connect to each other, while `vec` here is merely auxiliary.

Comment: Yeah I follow your reasoning. Sadly an ambiguous problem statement from OP.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
k   <- 4
n   <- 10
vec <- c(seq(-k+1, -1), seq(1, k+1))

outer(vec, vec, FUN = function(i, j) ifelse((i - j %% n) %in% vec, 1, 0))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    1
#[6,]    0    0    0    1    1    0    1    1
#[7,]    1    0    0    1    1    1    0    1
#[8,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    0
```

Comment: I have added the expected output.

Comment: @Nick Why is your expected output matrix symmetric? `i - j %% n` is not symmetric in `i` and `j`. So I expected the output matrix to not be symmetric. Am I missing something? Also, there was a typo in my code (I missed a bracket) which I've fixed.

Comment: I am thinking about symmetric/non_symmetric. Why is the size 8 by 8, but is not 10 by 10?

Comment: @Nick It's `8x8` because `vec` has only 8 elements. Why do you expect to get a `10x10` matrix?